# How to conditionally disable a react-native HeaderBackButton with a custom icon?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

What I want is a button that would be disabled while loading. What I came up with is:

```
Screen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  headerLeft: (
    <HeaderBackButton
      disabled={navigation.getParam('isBackDisabled')}
      onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
    />
  ),
})
```

but this is no good, because I want to have a custom icon for back button and this way it reverts to default icon. I also want that button to be visible even if disabled, so `headerLeft: null` is not viable.

Is there any way to disable it from outside of the component, or assign it the icon? Or where can I find the code for the animation to make my own `HeaderBackButton`?